# CSS, how to lign up 3 seperate containers side by side under a header in IE

Tags: css

pxI created a style defenition like this:

```
#container {
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image:url(images/back.JPG);
}
#header {
width: 900px;
height: 200px;
background-image:url(images/logo2.jpg);
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
#leftnav {
float:left;
width: 150px;
height: 500px;
}
#rightnav {
float:right;
width: 150px;
height: 500px;
}
#body {
margin-left: 150px;
width: 600px;
text-align:center;
background-image:url(images/tb.png);
}
#footer {
clear:both;
background-image:url(images/tb.png);
}
```

Then I created a index file like that used the container around everything, then put the header, then leftnav, then rightnav, then body, then footer.

This works greate on Chrome and firefox, but on IE, the "BODY" container is not where it is supposed to be, it starts under the "leftnav" container.  Is there a simple fix for this?

Updated cod from first answer, still same problem.

My index file is a php file.

Comment: Could you please provide a working example of your problem? The specific combination of HTML/CSS could be important (use http://jsfiddle.net for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have units defined on `#body`'s width. Should be `width: 600px;` 
Also, remove `margin-left: 150;`

Try this. It works in IE7 for me. I think you were just missing a doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Test for StackOverflow</title>
<style>
#container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image:url(http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/back.JPG);
}

#header {
    width: 900px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image:url(http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/logo2.jpg);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

#leftnav {
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
}

#rightnav {
    float:right;
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
}

#body {
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 600px;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url(http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/tb.png);
}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    background-image:url(http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/tb.png);
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="header">

</div>
<div id="leftnav"> 
  <img src="http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/p1.jpg" width="140" height="140"><br>
  <br>
  <img src="http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/p2.jpg" width="140" height="140"><br>
  <br>
  <img src="http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/p6.jpg" width="140" height="80"><br>

</div>
<div id="rightnav"> 
  <img src="http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/p3.jpg" width="140" height="80"><br>
  <br>
  <img src="http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/p4.jpg" width="140" height="80"><br>
  <br>
  <img src="http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/p5.jpg" width="140" height="80"><br>

</div>
<div id="body"> This Page is still under construction <br>
  <br>
  <img src="http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/images/logo3.jpg" width="550" height="362"> <br>
  <br>
</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but that did not help.  It made chrome and firefox fail, overlaying leftnav and body, and still kept the body under left nav in IE, but now ip put it on the left side. instead of in the middle.

Comment: What do you mean it fails? It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. You haven't given any height to your #body or #footer elements so, if they are divs, they won't display. Add the same height as #leftnav to them (150px). Is this what you are after?

Comment: I am sorry to use the word FAIL.  I mean the outcom is worse now than before.  You can go look at the site:  http://www.uffdarc.com/cantonspeedway/
I would like IE to display the page like Chrome does, as I feel that is the correct way.

Comment: copy/paste the code I added. Works for me in IE7. You'll have to put the paths to the images and CSS stylesheet back the way you like but give it a try first :)